# Auto refresh OAuth2 token paw

Tags: paw-app

I recently updated to the new Paw 3.

For our API we user OAuth2 authorization.

Ever since the update, the tokens do not automatically refresh. Are there any settings I need to edit? The `Automatically refresh or get token` option on all OAuth2 screens are turned on.

Comment: Should be fixed in the latest release (3.0.6)

Comment: I confirm this has been fixed for a while, and now Paw 3.0.14 also lets the OAuth 2 auto-refresh work for OAuth 2 tokens declared in an environment variable (Paw will lookup for used environment variables to perform auto-refresh).

Comment: How does paw know to refresh the token?  In our environment we get a 314 when timeout happen.  I want to write a custom extension when response has 314 update the token.  Is it possible to do so?  Can you please give some direction on how to do it.